# Relação entre 3 tabelas e buscar o resultado da última semana mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho três tabelas, a `tbl_recursos`, `tbl_categorias` e a `tbl_categoria_recurso`. A `tbl_recursos` consiste na listagem de recursos postados pelo utilizador. A `tbl_categorias` são as categorias que um recurso pode ter. E finalmente a `tbl_categoria_recurso` faz a relação entre os recursos e as categorias.

```
- tbl_recursos - 
id
data

- tbl_categorias -
id
nome

- tbl_categoria_recurso - 
id
id_recurso
id_categoria
```

O que eu quero fazer é listar o nome das categorias em que lhe foram associados mais recursos na ultima semana. Ou seja, o top 5 categorias com mais recursos na última semana. Estou a tentar fazer o seguinte consulta mas dá erro na data:

```
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_categorias cat WHERE 
                (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_categoria_recurso cat_r
                        JOIN tbl_recursos re
                        ON re.id = cat_r.id_recurso
                        WHERE cat_r.id_categoria = cat.id
                        AND (re.data >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
```

AND re.data < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY))");
                ?>
    ?>

O erro aparece na seguinte imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E a imagem que prova que o campo data existe na tbl_recursos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Compartilhe o erro.

Comment: @juniorb2ss adicionei a imagem em cima. obrigado

Comment: O erro se refere a inexistência ou desconhecimento da coluna requerida na condição. Você criou o alias `re` da `tbl_recursos`, correto. Tente retirar as aspas do `re.data`, ou alterar para `re`.`data`.

Comment: sim, o campo data existe. editei o post e meti a imagem da tbl_recursos. E também experimentei sem as aspas

Comment: Veja meu comentário, utilize `re`.`data`.

Comment: Não faltou um `EXISTS` logo após o primeiro `WHERE`?

Comment: @juniorb2ss, continua a dar erro na data. não percebo o porquê

Comment: @pc_oc já respondi, veja a resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei por usar a seguinte solução:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
    $data_actual = date("Y-m-d");
    $data_last_week = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data_actual. ' - 7 days'));


    $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(tbl_categoria_recurso.id_categoria) as contagem, tbl_categoria_recurso.id_categoria FROM tbl_recursos INNER JOIN tbl_categoria_recurso ON tbl_recursos.id=tbl_categoria_recurso.id_recurso WHERE data > '$data_last_week' GROUP BY id_categoria order by contagem desc LIMIT 5 ");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_categorias cat WHERE 
                    (
                        SELECT 1 FROM tbl_categoria_recurso cat_r
                        JOIN tbl_recursos r
                        ON `r`.`id` = cat_r.id_recurso
                        WHERE cat_r.id_categoria = `cat`.`id`
                        AND `r`.`data` >= (curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY)
                        AND `r`.`data` < (curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY)
                    )
                ");
```

Não entendi muito o que você realmente deseja retornar no subselect, até porque você esta efetuando uma condição na select primária capturando um registro da select secundária, você não deveria retornar o id para ser utilizado?

ou seja p.e:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_categorias cat WHERE (SELECT `cat_r`.`id` WHERE ...))
```

Comment: Eu ao tentar a sua consulta continua a dar erro nada data, não consigo perceber porque dá erro neste campo..

Comment: Me passe o schema pelo sqlfiddle.com, que irei montar a query.

Comment: aguarde só um pouco. obrigado

Comment: o sqlfiddle não me aceita o código sql gerado pelo phpmyadmin. é preciso fazer alguma alteração?

Comment: Não, é só inserir lá. Deve haver algumas diferenças de sintaxe, é só corrigir.

Comment: não estou a conseguir. Não conhece outra alternativa ao sqldiffle? peço desculpa

Comment: agora está aparecendo o seguinte erro: #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: Este erro e perante ao intervalo de dados, acredito. Minha sugestão seria  você tratar melhor isso diretamente no PHP e apenas informar a data na correta para a condição.

Comment: Sim, mas como poderia melhorar isto por PHP? A questão é que tenho que ir buscar o resultado 6 dias antes da data actual. obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Só procurar pela classe nativa do php de manipulação de datas.  Muito simples pegar a semana passada com ela.